# wrong data in ListView android

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Hi i've got small problem. In my app something gone wrong. I've made correct ArrayAdapter for List and in list view i see something like this. "com.example.blabla@14040", any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you are trying to show elements of a class and no strings. The ArrayAdapter is calling the toString() method and then it looks like you described. You could for example override the toString() method of your class and return the value of the property you want to see in the list.

Comment: The class Kategoria maybe has a property named Description or whatever you want to show in the list. Then you write in Kategoria: 

@Override
    public String toString() {
        return Description;
    }

Comment: The class Kategoria don't have that property. Someone else tell me to try getView method but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: Can you please post the code of the class Kategoria and tell me what exactly you expect to see in the list?

Comment: Im, expecting that the ListView will show all Categories names. For example, Sound, Screen ect.

Comment: So you have to insert this new funtion into the class Kategoria: @Override public String toString() { return kat_nazwa; }

Answer (score 0):

This may be an object that was converted to a string using a default toString implementation. The string representation of blabla probably needs to be obtained in some other way.